# Obtener id dinamicamente para ocultar y mostrar elementos

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Como puedo obtener los id de listas dinámicamente, por ejemplo..

```
<li>
  <a href="#">lista1</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#" onclick="ocultar;">lista2</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">lista3</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">lista4</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">lista5</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">lista5</a>
</li>
```

al pulsar cada elemento de lista estoy mostrando iframes con una funcion hasta ahora que obtiene dos id

```
function ocultar() {
    document.getElementById('DivDelista1').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('DivDelista2').style.display = "block";
};
```

(los id listas están relacionados con elementos iframe) entonces el detalle es que al presionar lista 2 por ejemplo se oculta el iframe de la `lista1` hasta ahí todo bien pero cuando este en `lista5` como ocultar la lista `x` que estaba en estado `display block` anteriormente?
ya que en la función estoy asignando los id de forma estatica,
hay alguna manera de saber que lista se presiono mostrarla y ocultar el iframe anterior cual sea que se haya seleccionado, estoy trabajando con un numero bastante grande de listas y es complicado agregar una función para cada una.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo mi solución:

```js
//Ocultamos todos los div al iniciar
$(".divlista").hide();

//Al hacer click en un elemento ocultamos todo 
//y mostramos el div indicado basado en el identificador del link
$(".lista").on("click",function(){
  $(".divlista").hide();
  $("#divlista"+ $(this).attr("id")).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a href="#" class="lista" id="1">lista1</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#" class="lista"  id="2">lista2</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#" class="lista"  id="3">lista3</a>
</li>

<div id="divlista1" class="divlista">
  DIV LISTA 1
</div>

<div id="divlista2" class="divlista">
  DIV LISTA 2
</div>

<div id="divlista3" class="divlista">
  DIV LISTA 3
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Las listas podrían compartir una clase, de esa manera podrías tenerlas a todas juntas en una sola variable, por ejemplo:

```
   var $listas = $('clase-compartida-por-las-listas');
```

Para después poder ocultarlas a todas agregando o quitando clases (es más performante que cambiar directamente el estilo y más limpio los estilos quedan en css y no en js)

Después en el evento onClick de cada lista ya te viene la lista clickeada. Si las listas se arman dinamicamente, el evento click debería colgarse del body, ej:

```
    $('body').on('click', 'clase-compartida-por-las-listas', function(event){
        var elementoClikeado = event.target;
       ...
     })
```

Answer (score 2):

Te recomendaría que usases clases para esto, entonces todo se podría hacer de manera más genérica sin necesidad de crear funciones para cada elemento de la lista.

Una opción entonces sería crear una clase "activa" que será visible, y entonces sólo tendrías que asignar/quitar esa clase al `div` correspondiente. Además para evitar tener que tener una función para cada `div`/`li` podrías guardar el objetivo dentro de un atributo `data-*` (o directamente en el href si no lo vas a utilizar).

Aquí dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$("ul li a").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("div.activo").removeClass("activo");
  $($(this).attr("href")).addClass("activo");
});
```

```css
div { 
  display:none; 
}
div.activo { 
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#DivDelist1">lista1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#DivDelist2">lista2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#DivDelist3">lista3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="DivDelist1" class="activo">Soy el DIV de la Lista 1</div>
<div id="DivDelist2">Soy el DIV de la Lista 2</div>
<div id="DivDelist3">Soy el DIV de la Lista 3</div>
```